# How to add ajax parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Faced with such a problem that you can't add parameters to ajax request, because there is a "Form Data" and it does not work to add more options. When you add in the parameter 'data' another variable, the error occurs. How to do that would be to post a file and parameters in one request?

Forgive the mistake, error or no, the php file simply does not output anything, rather empty values

```js
//Here the file is sent without problems, but the parameters no more don't accept php file, nothing displays in the result
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', input[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/controllers/createNewsController.php",
      data: fd,
      type: "POST",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".news .containers").append(data);
      }
    });
```

```
//When this code runs the PHP file won't take anything, although I was expecting the output variables and the file. Using var_dump, $_POST and $_FILES displays array(0){}
var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('file', input[0].files[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/controllers/createNewsController.php",
                    data: {fd, title:newsHeader, description:description, hashTag:hashTag, themeHashTag:themeHashTag, viewNews:viewNews},
                    type: "POST",
                    processData: false, 
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(data){
                        $(".news .containers").append(data);
                    } 
                });

//Similarly, nothing appears in the php file
var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('file', input[0].files[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/controllers/createNewsController.php",
                    data: {fd:fd, title:newsHeader, description:description, hashTag:hashTag, themeHashTag:themeHashTag, viewNews:viewNews},
                    type: "POST",
                    processData: false, 
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(data){
                        $(".news .containers").append(data);
                    } 
                });
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Post the code that gets the error.

Comment: You certainly are allowedto add more options, so you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Why not to use `fd.append('foo', 'bar')` or whatever you need? You can build FormData object and just pass it as you already did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you have appended the file, you can append more data into it like:

```
fd.append('file', input[0].files[0]);

fd.append('var1', val1);
fd.append('var2', val2);
```